# Adding multiple quantities of same product to quote

Tags: custom-field

does anyone know how to add several different quantities of the same product line to a quote on Salesforce without having to select the product individually each time?

Currently to add say a 4GB USB for quantities 25, 50, 100, 250 you have to enter 4GB USB 4 times.  Would be great if there was a search command to just enter it once and have it appear 4 times to enter each quantity

Answer (score 1):

Not out of the box no. There are a couple of appExchange apps that override the standard product functionality like "Rapid Products for Opportunities and Quotes" (https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009w8XPEAY) that should do the job.